# which compiler should I use with mex and windows

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, mex

I want to compile some cpp files using mex under windows (specifically - [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21310-maxflow)) . Which compiler should I download?

Answer (score 0):

According to the readme they tested it with Visual C++ 6.0 compiler. You can download Microsofts Express edition:
 http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express